# Python libraries after removing MacPorts and installing homebrew

Tags: python, macports, homebrew

I recently removed Macports and all its packages and installed Python, Gphoto and some other bits using Homebrew. However python is crashing when looking for libraries as it is looking for them in a MacPorts path. My PATH is correct and the python config show the right path /usr/local/Cellar etc.

Can someone tell me how to set Python to use the libraries installed via Homebrew, I suppose change the path effectively?

Comment: When you run `which python`, what do you get?

Comment: /usr/bin/python/ I did uninstall the homebrew one to see if the base framework one would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use the Macports packages in Homebrew. I'd reinstall them all.  A lot of Python packages are compiled , or at least have compiled elements.  You're asking for a lot of potential troubles mixing them up.

Comment: I don't want to Jon. A friend of mine has a camera app written for him and is a non developer. His developer advised MacPorts over ease of use. It wasn't working ( possibly due to Lion, Xcode Pygame whatever ). I uninstalled MacPorts completely installed  Python and its libraries via homebrew, but whenever I use the Homebrew Python ( or uninstall and use the Mac supplied one ) it is still looking for the libraries in /opt/local/somewhere.

Comment: 1. You probably have an issue with your env variables and a shell path.  You might be including something in there that is overriding what you intend.

2. Whether your want to or not, you *should* and *need to* reinstall the modules.  If you have, that's great.  If you haven't - if there is anything in there that compiled to c (which includes pygame, imaging, dbs, many hardware interaction libraries, most crypto packages etc) you're going to run into a lot of troubles.

There are a handful of questions here about how to completely remove a homebrew , macports, etc install.  I'd read those.